# Location of Room Database on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, android-room

I wrote an Android Native Jetpack Compose application, which uses a Room database. I’ve searched on the web to find articles on where the database is actually located on the device. The answer seems to be `/data/data/’. I’m using IntelliJ, and with the emulator I am using, that is where the database is located.

However, on my Samsung Galaxy S20 FE, there is no entry for my application in `/data/data`. My wife has a Pixel, and the database is not there on her phone either.

Anyone know where the database might be?

Comment: How are you looking in `/data/data/`? My guess is that you do not have rights to view what is in there.

Comment: It might just be because I'm using the IntelliJ emulator. What you say makes sense though, which is probably why we can't see it on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running these commands:

`adb shell` <- connects to your device

`run-as <app id>` <- if it's a debug build, this allows get into your app's space. `application id == package name`

`ls` <- shows app files, incl. `databases`